# Validate data by serializer and than get plain but valid json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I want to make validation of users input by serializers but after validation I want to get dict with json types (str, int, bool, float not python instances) without excess fields that could be passed by user.
Example:

```
    serializer = SomeSerializer(data=request.data)
    # request.data = {'a':'abc', 'some_primary_key':33, 'c':'abc'}
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # serializer has fields 'a' and 'some_primary_key' and doesn't have 'c'
        serializer.validated_data == {'a': 'abc', 'some_primary_key': <python instance with pk=33>}
```

How can I get something like this `serializer.plain_validated_data == {'a': 'abc', 'some_primary_key':33}` after validation?

Comment: what are you getting now?

Comment: @Exprator I get instances of python objects in validated data. For example if field 'x' has type UUIDField in serializer then I will get {'x': <instance of UUIDField>} in validated data. But I wan't to get just strings, after checking that 'x' realy has UUIDField type.

Comment: instance.the_field_name will give you the result

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get it would be to serialize the deserialization's result:

```
serializer = SomeSerializer(data=request.data)
# request.data = {'a':'abc', 'some_primary_key':33, 'c':'abc'}
if serializer.is_valid():
    # serializer has fields 'a' and 'some_primary_key' and doesn't have 'c'
    output_serializer = SomeSerializer(instance=serializer.validated_data)
    output_serializer.data == {'a': 'abc', 'some_primary_key':33}
```